# Removing a window event listener in Template.onDestroyed

Tags: meteor, vimeo-api, flow-router

I have two templates that each contain a Vimeo `iframe` player. I'm using FlowRouter to render the templates through `{{> Template.dynamic template=main}}` on the main layout.

In both templates I add listeners for video events in `onCreated`

```
Template.view.onCreated( function() {
    var self = this;

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            viewMessageReceived(event, self)}, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onmessage', function(event){
            viewMessageReceived(event, self)}, false);
    }
});
```

and destroy them in `onDestroyed`

```
Template.view.onDestroyed( function() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        console.log('view remove');
        window.removeEventListener('message', function(event) {
            viewMessageReceived(event, self)}, false);
    } else {
        window.detachEvent('onmessage', function(event){
            viewMessageReceived(event, self)}, false);
    }
});
```

And here is the function being called by the anonymous event handler:

```
function viewMessageReceived(event, self) {
// Handle messages from the vimeo player only
    if (!(/^https?:\/\/player.vimeo.com/).test(event.origin)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (self.playerOrigin === '*') {
        self.playerOrigin = event.origin;
    }

    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

    switch (data.event) {
        case "ready":
            initializePlayer(self);
            break;
        case "playProgress":
            self.playerTime.set(data.data.seconds);
            if (self.duration === '*') self.duration = data.data.duration;
            break;
        case "play":
            self.playerStatus.set("playing");
            break;
        case "pause":
            self.playerStatus.set("paused");
            break;
    }
}
```

When I switch to a different template, `onDestroyed` runs and my `console.log('view remove')` fires, as expected.

But then when I navigate to the page that loads the other template with a video player, a Vimeo "playProgress" `message` arrives that is received by the event handler in the **previous** video template, which was supposed to have been removed a while ago. This throws an error because the previous template has been destroyed.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined
```

which comes from the last line in this function:

```
function post(template, action, value) {
    console.log('view action: %s value: %s', action, value);
    var data = {method: action};
    if (value) data.value = value;
    var message = JSON.stringify(data);
    template.player[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, template.playerOrigin);
}
```

Each of the video-containing templates have their own .js file, so they each have a their own `post` function declaration. My understanding is that defining a function that way scopes the function just to the page.

It's only one message that arrives for the wrong player. After that, they arrive for the currently loaded player.

Why does the Vimeo message event arrive or get handled after I've already destroyed the template and when I've moved to another player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from the W3Schools website regarding the `removeEventListener()` method:

```
// Attach an event handler to <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);

// Remove the event handler from <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
```

> Note: To remove event handlers, the function specified with the
>   addEventListener() method must be an external function, like in the
>   example above (myFunction).
>
> Anonymous functions, like "element.removeEventListener("event",
>   function(){ myScript });" will not work.

For this to work, you'll need to move your function definition somewhere outside of the `onRendered` and `onDestroyed` events, and just pass the function name in the add/remove event listeners.

Comment: I originally had it that way, but still had the same problem.

Comment: I don't see a place anywhere in your code where you call the `post` function? It would be helpful to know how that function is being called. Is the Vimeo player itself being destroyed somehow? Even though the event listener is being removed from the first template, artifacts of the player could still be hanging around in the DOM, and/or in memory. When the second template loads it could be reloading data from the first template's player instance, since global variables don't get wiped out in Meteor between page routes.

Comment: `post` is called whenever anything on the page wants to interact with the player. In this place it's called by the `intializePlayer` function not seen.

Your answer was correct, though. Although I was attaching an external function to the EventListener, I was defining that function *inside* of `Template.onCreated`, meaning `Template.onDestroyed` didn't have access to it.

The solution was to declare an empty function in the top level `var viewMessageReceived = function(event) { }` and then redefine that function inside `Template.onCreated` where I have access to the template through `this`.